# How to properly format app.yaml to host Flutter web app with PHP backend

Tags: php, flutter-web, app.yaml

I'm trying to create a .yaml file for a flutter web app with a php backend, but I'm running into strange issues.

The app is structured as follows:

The flutter app is in Admin/web/ and includes various file types but no php files. The landing page is index.html.

The PHP backend is in Admin/ . All PHP files will need to be from Admin/

It currently loads index.html, but for some reason when I try website.com/manifest.json, I get index.html again. The same applies to FontManifest.json -- it gives me index.html.

It does work with the website root directory (website.com/), index.html, and main.dart.js -- the corresponding files are transmitted accurately.

Here's my .yaml file:

```
service: admin
runtime: php72


handlers:

  - url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    login: admin
    secure: always


  - url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    login: admin
    secure: always


  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    static_files: Admin/\1
    upload: Admin\/(.+\.php)$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: Admin/web/index.html
    upload: Admin/web/(.*)$
    login: admin
    secure: always
```

I noticed that the page immediately redirects from website.com/ to website.com/#/, so I also tried this .yaml file:

```
service: admin
runtime: php72

handlers:

  - url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /#/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /#/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    static_files: Admin/\1
    upload: Admin\/(.+\.php)$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: Admin/web/index.html
    upload: Admin/web/(.*)$
    login: admin
    secure: always
```

Still, with this .yaml file, I get the same results.

*Edit*
I realized that the previous .yaml file would yield the same results as the original due to the order of handlers, so I tried the following (and got the same results):

```
service: admin
runtime: php72

handlers:

  - url: /#/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /#/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    static_files: Admin/\1
    upload: Admin\/(.+\.php)$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: Admin/web/index.html
    upload: Admin/web/(.*)$
    login: admin
    secure: always
```

Comment: Are you totally sure that your `manifest.json` and `FontManifest.json` are inside `Admin/web/`?

Comment: Also, there is a notice in the docs `Static files cannot be the same as application code files.` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#handlers_element

Comment: BTW, are your PHP files works as expected? It looks like they shouldn't work, because static files are not executable. You should serve it via `entrypoint`

Comment: Yes, it's `Admin/web/manifest.json` and `Admin/web/assets/FontManifest.json`. I did not see a way to refer `/.*` to `/folder/.*` for script handlers. I'm not sure if the php was working. While testing I had used `entrypoint: server Admin/front.php`, so I just added that back per your suggestion.

Comment: There was I typo in my last comment. I added `entrypoint: serve Admin/front.php`

Comment: I'd rather get rid of that handler for `Admin/web/index.html` and served it via PHP entrypoint.

Comment: I have no specified rule for serving my json files, but it looks like I can access `*.json` files from WP plugins directly

Comment: Alright, makes sense. How do you access `*.json` files without a handler?

Comment: It looks like my `entrypoint: php serve gae-app.php` serves my assets. I used this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard to configure my WordPress project

Comment: I finally figured it out. Omitting the `$` at the end of the patterns was the key to getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*

The reason was apparently that the upload handler needs only to keep the capture group of the extension. Why this is I am unaware.

So, here's a more correct answer, although I am missing the reason behind this.

```
service: admin
runtime: php72

entrypoint: serve Admin/front.php

handlers:

  - url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))$
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart)$
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /
    static_files: Admin/web/index.html
    upload: Admin/web/index.html
    login: admin
    secure: always
```

*--Old version--*

Ok, so the secret was to not end the URL patterns with `$`.

Here is the working page:

```
service: admin
runtime: php72

entrypoint: serve Admin/front.php

handlers:

  - url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))
    static_files: Admin/web/\1
    upload: Admin/web/(.+\.(htm|html|css|js|json|map|ttf|dart))
    login: admin
    secure: always

  - url: /
    static_files: Admin/web/index.html
    upload: Admin/web/index.html
    login: admin
    secure: always
```

I used `entrypoint: serve Admin/front.php` to serve the php.

Comment: I guess it's still better to have `$` in your patterns with extensions to avoid false resolving for files like `my.cool.mapper.php`. Maybe not the best example, but I hope it's clear why you need it with extension patterns

Comment: Very good point. Unfortunately it did not work with the `$`, so I don't see much of a choice. It is pretty rare to have a file like `manifest.json.php` though, so it's workable.

Comment: Doesn't it work for you even if you leave remove `$` only near the `- url: /` and keep it everywhere else?

Comment: Also, it looks like you can combine your 1st and 2nd handlers

Comment: Ok, so I rechecked the app.yaml reference and I noticed a difference in the use of parentheses between the `url:` and the `upload:`. If you can provide an answer, possibly including your last suggestion, and explain why the parenthesis are different, I can give you the bounty (which expires in 8 hours). Also, yes, removing the `$` only near the `- url: /` also worked.